# gridview and sqldatasource control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

i have a gridview which is populating from sql datasource defined at designed, i have configured sqldatasource to select, update and delete, i have a title field in my table which is primary key, it was working fine and updating the records too. until i removed the boundfields and placed templatefield and itemtemplate. after that i gets an error saying:

`You have specified that your update command compares all values on SqlDataSource 'SqlDataSource1', but the dictionary passed in for oldValues is empty.  Pass in a valid dictionary for update or change your mode to OverwriteChanges.`

if i make the ConflictDetection = "OverwriteChanges" it works fine but does not update..
the requirement for the itemtemplate is because i want to display footer template for new records and change the default edit and delete button to imagebutton...

How should i make it work using itemtemplate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the columns you want persisted by adding them to the gridview datakeynames collection.